# Merge cells in ultragrid

Tags: ultrawingrid

I am trying to merge the cells in ultragrid.

I have this 
abc 50 23
abc 50 37
def 50 37

I want 
abc 50 23
       37
def 50 37

his.dgDeviation.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Price"].MergedCellEvaluationType = MergedCellEvaluationType.MergeSameText;

his.dgDeviation.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Price"].MergedCellEvaluationType = MergedCellEvaluationType.MergeSameText;[This explains much more what exactly i want to acheive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmmLw.png)

Comment: I am new user. Question might need some formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to this

```
 public class CustomMergedCellEvaluator :  Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.IMergedCellEvaluator
    {
      public bool ShouldCellsBeMerged(UltraGridRow row1, UltraGridRow row2, UltraGridColumn column)
      {
        // check if the previous column cells are merged.
        return (row1.Cells[column.Index - 1].IsMergedWith(row2.Cells[column.Index - 1]));
      }
    }
```

And then

```
private void dgDeviation_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
      this.dgDeviation.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["ExcludeName"].MergedCellStyle = MergedCellStyle.Always;
      this.dgDeviation.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["ExcludeName"].MergedCellEvaluator = new CustomMergedCellEvaluator();
    }
```

Without a custom merge behavior, think/try what happens to checkbox column in the grid if we try to merge its cells.